# Calculating the feature vector having variable length

Tags: python, machine-learning, vector, feature-detection

I have applied contouring to the image and generated the feature vector. So my feture vector contains [Number_of_countours, position of each countours]
For eg, if number of countours are 17 then my feature vector would look like

> [17, 74, 185, 97, 194, 118, 176, 144, 181, 146, 166, 156, 176, 39,
> 154, 77, 172, 129, 133, 168, 142, 58, 132, 82, 140, 37, 127, 55, 141,
> 117, 105, 151, 112, 58, 99, 86, 108, 24, 99, 53, 117, 154, 98, 195,
> 120, 61, 72, 78, 82, 122, 64, 155, 78, 84, 55, 105, 65, 172, 53, 178,
> 71, 115, 53, 131, 64, 186, 35, 208, 90]

For eg, if the number of countor is 14 then feature vector is

> [14, 123, 182, 193, 224, 80, 181, 110, 189, 137, 161, 167, 173, 53,
> 155, 98, 170, 70, 142, 90, 152, 185, 136, 201, 146, 147, 125, 173,
> 132, 175, 120, 191, 138, 63, 119, 90, 129, 208, 98, 224, 156, 133, 98,
> 167, 106, 92, 52, 113, 63, 136, 49, 159, 61, 185, 48, 194, 75]

#### Goal:

I want to find the similarity measure between this vector so that the size of the vector remains same (for Bag of Features)
Can someone help me how to get the similarity between different feature vectors?

Comment: you can not "bag" any feature. In that case, you want a similarity between two shape descriptors, thus it may be different to a Lp distance. The problem is to design (choose) one that hold the properties you want (invariance to translation. rotation? zoom?). Please add some details to better explain your need: which image/object do you work with? Why using a contour descriptor?

Comment: Important: give the details by editing your post ([edit]), not in the comments only